# how to create switching tabs between the pages

Tags: php

I am creation online question paper for this i wants to add the previous ,next , submit button ( note; i need each page containg only one question ). If there is any link is there means please guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: you need to explain your question, its not clear

Comment: i dont you if you mean to this but : http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/834682-how-generate-new-row-each-row-button-click

Answer (score 0):

Use a session variable to store the current click count.